# Tags filter field - how to add custom "placeholder"?

Tags: custom-component, tags, form-fields-types, filter

I have added a tags filter in my component's list with multiple enabled.

```
<field
    name="tag"
    type="tag"
    label="-Select a Tag-"
    description="Filter by Tags"
    multiple="true"
    class="multipleTags"
    mode="nested"
    onchange="this.form.submit();">
</field>
```

It renders and work fine, with the only exception that in the field's input it displays a generic text "Type or Select some options". So, it isn't obvious at first sight about what this filter is about.

[image: Tags Filter]

I haven't found anything obvious yet, with my search in the core components that make use of the tags filters.

Anyone has any idea on **how can I replace that text to something like "Select a Tag"**?

Answer (score 2):

Create a language override for the constant:

JGLOBAL_TYPE_OR_SELECT_SOME_OPTIONS

1. Extensions > Languages > Overrides
2. Create a new override
3. Type/paste "JGLOBAL_TYPE_OR_SELECT_SOME_OPTIONS" as the Language Constant
4. Type "Select a Tag" into the Text field.
5. Check "For both Locations" if you want it to say the same thing in the front and backend.
6. Save and close

It looks like this when you're done (I typed different "Text" because I'm a funny guy)

[image]

Comment: @FFrewin is this question resolved?